# Collecting tweets using Twitter4j by user's location and time frame

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-rest-api

I'm currently getting tweets using Twitter4j an unofficial Java library for the Twitter API but my question is how to get a big data set of tweets from different users that don't have a keyword in common but do have their location in common. I know there is geolocation but not everyone shares their location every time they tweet so it would be good if I could search users that their profile says are from a certain location and then get tweets from users with a location in common and an specific time frame.

Comment: users may include location in their profile, see [user entity](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users), look for the field `location`. This field is filled in more often than the geolocation, however it is difficult to parse. Even if that was ok, still you don't have a query of *users per location*, not even *users per geolocation*. I guess the closest is [GET trends/place](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) but I've never used it. Hope it helps

Comment: Got any update regarding how to implement this scenario?